# Python quits after a constructor is called

Tags: python

My code seems to be failing after the constructor is called.
Here is my code - it is failing on the `c = create_control_point()` line in `main()`:

```
from brisa.core.reactors import install_default_reactor

reactor = install_default_reactor()
print reactor

from brisa.core.threaded_call import run_async_function
from brisa.upnp.control_point.control_point import ControlPoint
from datetime import datetime

service = ('u', 'urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:SwitchPower:1')
binary_light_type = 'urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:BinaryLight:1'

def on_new_device(dev):    
    print 'Got new device:', dev.udn   
    print "Type 'list' to see the whole list"
    if not dev:
        return

def get_switch_service(device):
    return device.services[service[1]]

def create_control_point():
    c = ControlPoint()
    print "hello"   
    c.subscribe('new_device_event', on_new_device)  
    print "c"
    return c

def main():
    """ Main loop iteration receiving input commands.
    """
    print "hell"
    c = create_control_point()
    print "helllo"
    c.start()
    run_async_function(_handle_cmds, (c, ))
    reactor.add_after_stop_func(c.stop)
    reactor.main()

def _exit(c):
    """ Stops the _handle_cmds loop
    """
    global running_handle_cmds
    running_handle_cmds = False

def _search(c):
    """ Start searching for devices of type upnp:rootdevice and repeat
    search every 600 seconds (UPnP default)
    """
    c.start_search(600, 'upnp:rootdevice')

def _get_status(c):
    """ Gets the binary light status and print if it's on or off.
    """
    try:
        service = get_switch_service(c.current_server)
        status_response = service.GetStatus()
        if status_response['ResultStatus'] == '1':
            print 'Binary light status is on'
        else:
            print 'Binary light status is off'
    except Exception, e:
        if not hasattr(c, 'current_server') or not c.current_server:
            print 'BinaryLight device not set.Please use set_light <n>'
        else:
            print 'Error in get_status():', e

def _get_target(c):
    """ Gets the binary light target and print if it's on or off.
    """
    try:
        service = get_switch_service(c.current_server)
        status_response = service.GetTarget()
        if status_response['RetTargetValue'] == '1':
            print 'Binary light target is on'
        else:
            print 'Binary light target is off'
    except Exception, e:
        if not hasattr(c, 'current_server') or not c.current_server:
            print 'BinaryLight device not set.Please use set_light <n>'
        else:
            print 'Error in get_target():', e

def _stop(c):
    """ Stop searching
    """
    c.stop_search()

def _list_devices(c):
    """ Lists the devices that are in network.
    """
    k = 0
    for d in c.get_devices().values():
        print 'Device no.:', k
        print 'UDN:', d.udn
        print 'Name:', d.friendly_name
        print 'Device type:', d.device_type
        print 'Services:', d.services.keys() # Only print services name
        print
        k += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "hello"
    main()
```

I am getting the output:

```
ankit@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ python controlpt.py

<brisa.core.reactors.glib2.GLib2Reactor object at 0x88c3e0c>
hello
hell
```

Why isn't it getting to the `c = create_control_point()` line?  Also, the `controlpoint` constructor is quitting the whole program.
When I tried

```
$ python
>>> import controlpt
>>> controlpt.main()
```

I got the output:

```
>>> controlpt.main()
hell
ankit@ubuntu:~/Desktop$
```

Help?

Comment: pdb is your friend: http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Comment: @user616782: that code would be easier to read if you removed all the blank lines that appear between each line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's dying on the `ControlPoint` initialization, have you tried the following in the interpreter?

```
from brisa.upnp.control_point.control_point import ControlPoint
c = ControlPoint()
```

If that works, then there's something else at play.

Comment: So did `c` get set to an instance of `ControlPoint()`?  If so, then using a debugger like PDB may be worth your time so you can step through the code and be able to gracefully handle any sort of exception when it happens.

Comment: It is breaking at c = Controlpoint(). I tried to "from brisa.upnp.control_point.control_point import ControlPoint" then print "Hi" and the c = Controlpoint()....And it then print "HI" and after that it quits.