# initialization problem in Python

Tags: python

The error is given at the end:

```
from brisa.core.reactors import install_default_reactor   
reactor = install_default_reactor()    
print reactor    

from brisa.upnp.control_point.control_point import ControlPoint    
def on_new_device(dev):        

    print 'Got new device:', dev.udn    
    print "Type 'list' to see the whole list"    
    if not dev:    
        return

def create_control_point():   
    c = ControlPoint()    
    print "hello"       
    c.subscribe('new_device_event', on_new_device)      
    print "c"    
    return c    

def main():    
    print "Inside main"             
    c = create_control_point()    
    print "Inside create control point"
    c.start()    
    reactor.add_after_stop_func(c.stop)    
    reactor.main()

def _search(c):    
    """ Start searching for devices of type upnp:rootdevice and repeat    
    search every 600 seconds (UPnP default)    
    """    
    c.start_search(600, 'upnp:rootdevice')    

def _stop(c):    
    """ Stop searching    
    """    
    c.stop_search()     

def _list_devices(c):    
    """ Lists the devices that are in network.    
    """    
    k = 0    
    for d in c.get_devices().values():    
        print 'Device no.:', k    
        print 'UDN:', d.udn    
        print 'Name:', d.friendly_name    
        print 'Device type:', d.device_type    
        print 'Services:', d.services.keys() # Only print services name    
        print
        k += 1

# Control the loop at _handle_cmds function
running_handle_cmds = True
commands = {             
            'search': _search,
            'stop': _stop,
            'list': _list_devices,            
            }

def _handle_cmds(c):
    while running_handle_cmds:
        try:
            input = raw_input('>>> ').strip()
            if len(input.split(" ")) > 0:
                try:
                    if len(input.split(" ")) > 1:
                        commands[input.split(" ")[0]](c, input.split(" ")[1])
                    else:
                        commands[input.split(" ")[0]](c)
                except KeyError, IndexError:
                    print 'Invalid command, try help'
                except TypeError:
                    print 'Wrong usage, try help to see'
        except KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError:
            c.stop()
            break

    # Stops the main loop
    reactor.main_quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    print "hello"    
    main()
```

Error:

```
ankit@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ python controlpt.py
<brisa.core.reactors.glib2.GLib2Reactor object at 0x965bdcc>
hello
Inside main
```

After that I know understand, it is not initialising the control point. The Information about the libraries(Control point) is available at http://brisa.garage.maemo.org/apidoc/index.html

Comment: please fix formatting if you want answers.

Comment: @user616782: Please remove all but the minimal number of blank lines.

Comment: Is it exact duplicate of your another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020732/python-quits-after-a-contructor-is-called)?

Comment: dont see the duplication....plz try to figure out the problem. I have mentioned the link where the libraries are. In the previous question, it was not there.

Comment: @user616782: Please do not post status comments.  Please delete useless and uninformative comments like "ok wait" and "please see the updated version".  They no longer make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is anything like some other event-based libraries such as Twisted, you want to get the reactor's main running before you do much of anything else.

Drop the call to `reactor.main` in your main function.  Then, instead of just calling `main` in your `if` at the bottom, do this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_async_function(main)
    reactor.main()
```

See if things behave more like what you expect then.

(`run_async_function` is in the `threaded_call` module.)

Comment: ya,..i tried but it doesnt work.The program hangs at the terminal window at the c= create_control_point()